# el énfasis: pluscuamperfecto en vez de imperfecto (caso particular)

Tags: tiempos-verbales, pretérito-imperfecto

¿Si digo *había empezado a hablar* en vez de *empezaba a hablar* (en el contexto siguiente), cómo cambia el énfasis/significado?

> Cuando vieron que el sordomudo **empezaba a hablar**, todos pensaron
>   que era un milagro.
>
> Cuando vieron que el sordomudo **había empezado a hablar**, todos
>   pensaron que era un milagro.

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El pretérito imperfecto tiene varios usos, entre los cuales se pueden distinguir dos especialmente frecuentes:

- El pretérito imperfecto se suele usar para una acción repetida (**interpretación cíclica**),
- o una co-ocurrente o vinculada en el tiempo a otra (**interpretación deíctica**).

Según la primera interpretación, solo el imperfecto es válido; según la segunda, ambas formas pueden ser intercambiables hasta cierto punto según el contexto. Así, en una frase del estilo *"Cuando Carlos empezaba a hablar, todos sabían que la cosa iba a ir para largo"*, se ve la interpretación cíclica, donde "había empezado" no es válido para expresar una acción que se da de forma repetida en el pasado. De hecho, si se usara el pluscuamperfecto, esto es: *"Cuando Carlos había empezado a hablar, todos sabían que la cosa iba a ir para largo"*, se cambiaría de una interpretación cíclica (el hecho de que Carlos hablaba era una acción frecuente) a una deíctica, donde la acción de que Carlos empiece a hablar se da a la vez o después de que los demás sepan que la cosa iba a ir para largo. El mismo significado queda más claro añadiendo algunos términos superfluos:

> Para cuando Carlos había empezado a hablar, todos ya sabían que la cosa iba a ir para largo.

En la oración anterior, primero todos saben que la cosa va a ir para largo, y luego (o al mismo tiempo) Carlos empieza a hablar. No se dice en ningún momento que el hecho de que Carlos hablaba era algo que solía hacer, inferencia más que probable en la primera oración. Esa es la diferencia entre la interpretación deíctica y la cíclica.

Lo más lógico sería pensar que en tu caso se da la interpretación deíctica, y que por tanto ambas formas son correctas. Sin embargo, existe un pequeño cambio de significado entre ambas:

### Cuando vieron que el sordomudo empezaba a hablar...

Con el imperfecto ("empezaba"), la interpretación cíclica queda descartada porque esta exigiría el imperfecto también en las demás formas, esto es: "Cuando veían que el sordomudo empezaba a hablar, todos pensaban que era un milagro", lo cual podría tener sentido en un escenario donde el sordomudo solía empezar a hablar en frente de nuevas personas cada vez, y estas cada vez pensaban que era un milagro. Solo queda la interpretación deíctica, donde las acciones de "ver", "empezar a hablar" y "pensar que es un milagro" ocurren todas al mismo tiempo.

### Cuando vieron que el sordomudo había empezado a hablar...

Con el pluscuamperfecto ("había empezado") solo la interpretación deíctica es posible, y según esta "pensar que es un milagro" puede haber ocurrido o a la vez o después de que el sordomudo haya empezado a hablar. Esto es, el sordomudo podría haber empezado a hablar hace una semana, pero solo ahora la gente se ha dado cuenta.

---

En conclusión, el imperfecto es algo más restringido que el pluscuamperfecto en el sentido de que define mejor el marco temporal de las tres acciones, aunque la diferencia entre ambos es muy sutil y en la mayoría de los casos incluso nimia.